# How do we specify lower and upper bound for different variables in BRMS package in R?

Tags: r, jags, rstan

I am trying to run Bayesian Logistic regression on Household Panel data (huge dataset with > 1.2 million rows) using BRMS package R. My code is as below:

```
my_prior <- c(prior(beta(2,30),class='b',coef='X1'),
              prior(beta(10,30),class='b',coef='X2'))

model <- brm(data=train,family='bernoulli',Y ~ X1+X2,
prior = my_prior,warmup = 3000,chains = 5,cores=5,seed=12345,iter=5000)
```

This gives below error:

```
Rejecting initial value:
Chain 1:   Error evaluating the log probability at the initial value.
Chain 1: Exception: beta_lpdf: Random variable is -0.243779, but must be >= 0!  (in 'model31883818b7d_f587f3632d3e0a9838716955c8523c09' at line 31)
```

Although I have given Beta priors to both X1 and X2 (it should limit between 0 and 1 by property of Beta distribution), Variable gets initialized with out of bound values and throws error.

Further, I specified lower and upper bound on parameters as below:

my_prior <- c(prior(beta(2,30),class='b',coef='X1',**lb=0,ub=1**),
                  prior(beta(10,30),class='b',coef='X2'))

It throws error as below:

```
Coef may not be specified using boundaries
```

Can anyone help me how to specify bounds (different for different parameters) ?

I have even used Rstan and jags but they take lot of time on such huge dataset.